# Discrepancy emmeans in R (using ezAnova) vs estimated marginal means in SPSS

Tags: r, statistics, spss

So this is a bit of a hail mary, but I'm hoping someone here has encountered this before. I recently switched from SPSS to R, and I'm now trying to do a mixed-model ANOVA. Since I'm not confident in my R skills yet, I use the exact same dataset in SPSS to compare my results.

I have a dataset with

> dv = RT
>
> within = Session (2 levels), Cue (3 levels), Flanker (2 levels)
>
> between = Group(3 levels).
>
> no covariates.
>
> unequal number of participants per group level (25,25,23)

In R I'm using the ezAnova package to do the mixed-model anova:

```
results <- ezANOVA(
    data = ant_rt_correct
    , wid = subject
    , dv = rt
    , between = group
    , within = .(session, cue, flanker) 
    , detailed = T
    , type = 3
    , return_aov = T
)
```

In SPSS I use the following GLM:

```
GLM rt.1.center.congruent rt.1.center.incongruent rt.1.no.congruent rt.1.no.incongruent 
rt.1.spatial.congruent rt.1.spatial.incongruent rt.2.center.congruent rt.2.center.incongruent 
rt.2.no.congruent rt.2.no.incongruent rt.2.spatial.congruent rt.2.spatial.incongruent BY group 
/WSFACTOR=session 2 Polynomial cue 3 Polynomial flanker 2 Polynomial 
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3) 
/EMMEANS=TABLES(group*session*cue*flanker) 
/PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE 
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05) 
/WSDESIGN=session cue flanker session*cue session*flanker cue*flanker session*cue*flanker 
/DESIGN=group.
```

The results of which line up great, ie:

> R: Session F(1,70) = 46.123 p = .000
>
> SPSS: Session  F(1,70) = 46.123 p = .000

I also ask for the means per cell using:

```
descMeans <- ezStats(
    data = ant_rt_correct
    , wid = subject
    , dv = rt
    , between = group
    , within = .(session, cue, flanker) #,cue,flanker)
    , within_full = .(location,direction)
    , type = 3
)
```

Which again line up perfectly with the descriptives from SPSS, e.g. for the cell:

> Group(1) - Session(1) - Cue(center) - Flanker(1)
>
> R: M = 484.22
>
> SPSS: M = 484.22

However, when I try to get to the estimated marginal means, using the emmeans package:

```
eMeans <- emmeans(results$aov, ~ group | session | cue | flanker)
```

I run into descrepancies as compared to the Estimated Marginal Means table from the SPSS GLM output (for the same interactions), eg:

> Group(1) - Session(1) - Cue(center) - Flanker(1)
>
> R: M = 522.5643
>
> SPSS: M = 484.22

It's been my understanding that the estimated marginal means should be the same as the descriptive means in this case, as I have not included any covariates. Am I mistaken in this? And if so, how come the two give different results?

Since the group sizes are unbalanced, I also redid the analyses above after making the groups of equal size. In that case the emmeans became:

> Group(1) - Session(1) - Cue(center) - Flanker(1)
>
> R: M =521.2954
>
> SPSS: M = 482.426

So even with equal group sizes in both conditions, I end up with quite different means. Keep in mind that the rest of the statistics and the descriptive means áre equal between SPSS and R. What am I missing... ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The plot thickens.. If I perform the ANOVA using the AFEX package:

```
results <- aov_ez(
    "subject"
    ,"rt"
    ,ant_rt_correct 
    ,between=c("group")
    ,within=c("session", "cue", "flanker") 
    )
)
```

and then take the emmeans again:

```
eMeans <- emmeans(results, ~ group | session | cue | flanker)
```

I suddenly get values much closer to that of SPSS (and the descriptive means)

> Group(1) - Session(1) - Cue(center) - Flanker(1)
>
> R: M = 484.08
>
> SPSS: M = 484.22

So perhaps ezANOVA is doing something fishy somewhere?

Comment: For starters, you can't just make up syntax that you think ought to work. In this case, the expression `~ group | session | cue | flanker` has no meaning in the `emmeans()` function. Only one `|` can be there (I have no idea what it will do with your specifications, and I an the package developer). Read the documentation and decide what's appropriate. I think you want `~ group * session * cue * flanker` given your SPSS code. (cont'd next comment)

Comment: Offhand, the main reasons I can think of that you would get discrepancies are: (1) the model you fitted in R is not equivalent to the model you fitted in SPSS. (that seems the more likely one); and (2) SPSS defines EMMs differently, perhaps some kind of weighted averages. But I'd concentrate on (1). It's not an issue (at least yet) with **emmeans** if your regression coefficients, random-effect estimates, etc.don't match. First things first.

Comment: I'd also comment that it's really, really, really, really hard to understand what kind of model you are trying to fit in SPSS. I don't use SPSS, but that just plain looks like a real mess. The presence of multiple instances of `.spatial` convinces me that your `aov_ez` model is not even close to the one you fitted in SPSS.

Comment: Hi rvl, thanks for you comments. As to your first point, the ~  with the multiple |  gives me the exact same output as the * formatted syntax, in terms of emmeans, but the output is formatted a little more accessibly (and any adjustments like bonferroni will of count the levels differently). As for the SPSS model, I'm afraid that's the way it's supposed to look. SPSS takes wide-formatted data with each cell mean represented in a different variable. I agree it looks shitty, but that's just the way it work..

Comment: So, I also figured the models might be specified differently, but all the other model statistics are exactly the same between ezAnova, AFEX (aov_ez) and SPSS. With just the emmeans output differing between the three. Given that the emmeans output for the aov_ez model seems much more like the SPSS data (and the expected means) I'm thinking it's an issue with ezAnova (and not with emmeans).

Comment: Just to clarify, with the `~ group * session * cue * flanker` syntax the problem persist

Comment: If the results are different, I am almost certain that the models are different. It appears you have specified a complicated correlation structure with the spss model, and a much simpler structure with the R models.

Comment: Hi rlv, I'm confident that the SPSS model is correct. But even if that were not the case, it doesn't seem to explain the difference between the emmeans based on the AFEX and ezANOVA packages (despite the test statistics being the same)... And it doesn't explain why the emmeans (based on the ezANOVA output) are so far removed from the descriptive means (when no covariate is included in the model).

Comment: I tried to compare the `$aov` objects from both models, and what struck me was that for the emmeans based on ezANOVA, the first reported cell mean in the fully specified model `~ group * session * cue * flanker` is exactly the intercept coefficient. And while the `$aov` object from the AFEX package has the same intercept, the value in the first reported emmeans level is pretty much equal to the descriptive means (and not to the intercept).. In other words: `Intercept AFEX: 522 , Intercept ezANOVA:  522` ,  `emmeans_AFEX: 483, emmeans_ezANOVA: 522` , `descriptive_means: 483`

Comment: I believe `ezANOVA` fits a fixed-effects model, whereas `aov_ez` fits a mixed model with `groups` as a random factor. The latter seems more similar to the mixed model you have fitted in SPSS. The **ez** package provides another function for fitting a mixed model, but it is not compatible with **emmeans**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try this:

```
library(lme4)    ### I'm guessing you need to install this package first
mod <- lmer(rt ~ session + cue + flanker + (1|group),
            data = ant_rt_correct)

library(emmeans)
emm <- emmeans(mod, ~ session * cue * flanker)
pairs(emm, by = c("cue", "flanker")        # simple comparisons for session
pairs(emm, by = c("session", "flanker")    # simple comparisons for cue
pairs(emm, by = c("session", "cue")        # simple comparisons for flanker
```

This fits a mixed model with random intercepts for each group. It uses REML estimation, which is likely to be what SPSS uses.

In contrast, `ezANOVA` fits a fixed-effects model (no within factor at all), and `aov_ez` uses the `aov` function which produces an analysis that ignores the inter-block effects. Those make a difference especially with unbalanced data.

An alternative is to use `afex::mixed`, which in fact uses `lme4::lmer` to fit the model.